# Difficulty Creating a Set of Variance Data

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to create a series of data that plots the variance in a data point. The difficulty I am having is that the statement depends not just on subtracting the previous row's data point. The data points are mixed with each other randomly.

I have a list of wells and each well has the temperature reading for each date. For a given day, there are about 100 temperature recordings, one for each well. I want the variance plot to be the data of the current day minus the previous day temperature of that specific well.

Currently I have two index columns that I use to subtract the current index from the previous. However, the mistake it makes is that the index columns don't line up correctly with the well and its date. For example, X1A on June 1 is index 0 in the first index column, but is then October 14th in index 1. The variance plot will record the temperature difference between these two dates, rather than June 2 minus June 1.

I think to fix it will require a specific setting before declaring my two index columns, but I'm not sure how to do so. Currently, the index columns are aligned just per well, so it is subtracting the wells data, just not in the correct order. Any help will be greatly appreciated. I have included a screenshot just for extra clarity.

The code for my column that calculates the temperature variance looks like this:

```
      TempVariation = Var Diff = 'Zone 2 Max'[Zone 2 Max Temp] - 
      Calculate(SUM('Zone 2 Max'[Zone 2 Max Temp]),FILTER('Zone 2 Max','Zone 
      2 Max'[Index.1] = EARLIER('Zone 2 Max'[Index]))) return 
      IF(Diff=Value('Zone 2 Max'[Zone 2 Max Temp]),0,Diff)
```

[Attached Screenshot of Table and How It Currently is Wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHUgl.png)

This is how I want my table to look so that I can make a graph of the change in temperature when a user selects a certain well.
| Date | Well | Temp | Change in Temp From Previous Day |
|:------|:------:|:------:|----------------------------------:|
|July 1| A1P  | 74   |               0                  |
|July 1| A2P  | 78   |               0                  |
|July 1| A3P  | 41   |               0                  |
|July 2| A1P  | 75   |               1                  |
|July 2| A1P  | 70   |              -8                  |
|July 2| A1P  | 38   |              -3                  |
|July 3| A1P  | 72   |               -3                 |
|------|------|------|----------------------------------|

Comment: You need to provide sample data in text format and expected output. There is also no X1A in your screenshot.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @David The X1A is an example of how I have tried to set it up. The first index in the table is A1P on July 1, 2013. The next index is A1P on January 25th, 2015. This causes the temperature variance calculation to be the value on Jan25 2015 minus July1 2013, rather than it being July2 2013 - July1 2013. An expected output would 0 for these two selected dates because the data doesn't actually begin recording until July 10th.

Comment: Why are you using EARLIER() - it is effectively deprecated now that we have VAR.
Why do you have two indexes? If you just need the value from the previous date, you don't need any indexes. If you provide sample data in text format and expected output, either myself or someone can provide the code for you.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302471/how-to-put-tables-in-stack-overflow

Comment: @David The data comes in three columns: date, well, and temperature. The indexes are how I am currently doing the calculation but I can delete them when I find a better solution. The row starts at the first well, and the first date (July 1st) has about 100 corresponding rows for each of the wells measured temp on that date before moving to the next date, restarting from the top well and reporting the temperature on that day. For a given well, I want to take the previous days temp value and subtract it from todays temp to find the difference.

Comment: @David See my updated post with the included table please and thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

I've found an answer to my own problem using what I currently already have created:

I sorted my wells firstly by well name ascending, then by date ascending and from there added two index columns starting at 0 and 1. The sorting of the rows corrected my previous mistake, as now the first index starts on July 1 on the first well, and it increments for the one well per day. From there, the calculation shown in the question remained the same, just subtracting the earlier value from the current to get change in temperature.